# Non-NULL datetime values retrieved as NULL when Django server put behind Apache

Tags: mysql, django, apache

I'm having a weird problem that's only reproducible in my prod environment. I have some Django code:

```
from report.models import Report
report = Report.objects.get(id=1)
completed_datetime = report.completed_datetime
```

On prod `completed_datetime` will be `None` even though the value in the database is not NULL. Normally when I have a bug like this, my approach is to reproduce the problem in the shell or in `runserver` where I can use `pdb` to observe the problem more closely. However, when I execute the identical code in the shell on the same database, I get the correct value.

Since the problem completely goes away when running the server with `runserver` I've had to take a different approach. One thing I have tried is adding the following line to the end:

```
report_dict = report.__dict__
```

which when inspected on prod has `None` for the attribute `completed_datetime`, but is fine in any other environment.

I have not forgotten to restart Apache. I have tried zero-ing the tables and re-migrating everything, but to no avail. I am running Django 1.8 with MySQL 5.6.19 and Apache 2.2.22. Any suggestions on how to debug this problem further?